# C++ memory leaks with strings in a class

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm developing in Visual C++ 2010 and I'm using a library called "Visual Leak Detector" to check for memory leaks. Then I found one that I can't explain and solve.
Here is my code:

```
ManageRenderListenerCommand::ManageRenderListenerCommand(string action):mAction(action){
}

void ManageRenderListenerCommand::execute(){
    //Do something with action
}
```

The header file is:

```
class ManageRenderListenerCommand : public IOgreCommand{
private:
    string      mAction;
public:
    ManageRenderListenerCommand(string action);
    void execute();
};
```

**UPDATE:** It's called here:

```
void OgreMediator::onOgreChanged(AbstractOgreNegotiator* negotiator, NegotiatorEvent& negotiatorEvent){
    IOgreCommand* command = NULL;
    if(negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("addToViewport")){
        command = new AddToViewportCommand(mCameraManager, mSceneCreator, mEngine);
    }else if (negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("manageRenderListener")){
        command = new ManageRenderListenerCommand(negotiatorEvent.getMessage());
    }else if (negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("manageMouseCamera")){
        command = new ManageMouseCameraCommand(mCameraManager, mMouseManager->getLastEvent());
    }

    //Execute the created command
    if (command){
        command->execute();
        delete command;
    }
}
```

And the stacks of the four memory leaks are very similar, so here it's one of them:

```
---------- Block 163 at 0x023CEAE0: 8 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (36): CataractSimulator.exe!std::_Allocate<std::_Container_proxy> + 0x15 bytes
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (187): CataractSimulator.exe!std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>::allocate + 0xB bytes
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring (469): CataractSimulator.exe!std::_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> >::_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> > + 0xA bytes
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring (543): CataractSimulator.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > + 0x5F bytes
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\managerenderlistenercommand.cpp (10): CataractSimulator.exe!ManageRenderListenerCommand::ManageRenderListenerCommand
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\ogremediator.cpp (28): CataractSimulator.exe!OgreMediator::onOgreChanged + 0x53 bytes
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\abstractogrenegotiator.cpp (5): CataractSimulator.exe!AbstractOgreNegotiator::notifyMediator + 0x1C bytes
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\ogrerenderobserverregistry.cpp (37): CataractSimulator.exe!OgreRenderObserverRegistry::addListener + 0x15 bytes
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\ogremediator.cpp (73): CataractSimulator.exe!OgreMediator::addRenderListener
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\mousemanager.cpp (6): CataractSimulator.exe!MouseManager::startMouse
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\ogremediator.cpp (58): CataractSimulator.exe!OgreMediator::initFramework
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\simulatorapi.cpp (27): CataractSimulator.exe!SimulatorAPI::Facade::initFramework
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\simulatorapi.cpp (60): CataractSimulator.exe!SimulatorAPI::initFramework
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\loader.cpp (23): CataractSimulator.exe!Loader::Facade::initFramework + 0x16 bytes
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\simulator\src\loader.cpp (45): CataractSimulator.exe!Loader::go
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\cataractsimulator\src\cataractloader.cpp (5): CataractSimulator.exe!CataractLoader::go + 0x8 bytes
    c:\users\cps\desktop\surgery-sim\project\cataractsimulator\src\cataractloader.cpp (26): CataractSimulator.exe!main
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (555): CataractSimulator.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): CataractSimulator.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x7791ED6C (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
    0x77A1377B (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0xEF bytes
    0x77A1374E (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0xC2 bytes
  Data:
    14 4E 3D 02    00 00 00 00                                   .N=..... ........
```

Comment: There is no memory leak in the code you posted. The problem (if it exists) is somewhere else.

Comment: That's what I think! I can show you where this class is called

Comment: Does Command (or one of its Base classes) have a **virtual** destructor? I'm including abstract base classes and "interface" bases in that question. What is `IOgreCommand`, and how does `Command` relate to it?

Comment: No, it only has `execute()`, and Commant is the same, but an error in the post!I'm solving it

Comment: Is there a virtual destructor declared+defined for **any** of the Base classes of `class ManageRenderListenerCommand` ? If not you need to add one, and it should be in the `IOgreCommand` interface or deeper, by the looks of it.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Visual Leak Detector and unrelated code. Wish I knew if this problem was solved with a code change or if it is an issue with VLD.

Comment: It was finally solved by adding a default destructor to the parent class (in this case IOgreCommand). It is not an issue on VLD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If IOgreCommand (or any class that IOgreCommand derives from) doesn't have a virtual destructor, then any class that derives from IOgreCommand will not have its destructor called when deleting an IOgreCommand pointer.

Comment: Do I have to declare a destructor (although I don't destroy anything) on every command or only on the base `IOgreCommand`class?

Comment: @Feantury Just one is fine. The basic rule is: if you ever expect to handle a class through a pointer to a base class, that base class (the topmost one) should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: The main idea wasn't but some design rules changed and I forgot it! That was the problem! Thanks ;)

Comment: It might have its destructor called. The behavior is undefined, so there are no constraints on what it does.

Comment: The rule is that if you **delete** an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base type, the base type must have a virtual destructor; if it doesn't, the behavior of the program is undefined.